# Hide NavigatorIOS only on one view?

Tags: react-native

you can hide the NavigatorIOS bar by using `navigationBarHidden` property.

```jsx
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: Login,
          title: "Login"
        }}
        style={{
          flex: 1
        }}
        navigationBarHidden={true}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to adjust navigationBarHidden from within a view. Any help?